# Python: Retrieve post parameter from javascript button

Tags: javascript, python

I am programming in python a script to obtain statistical data of the public schools of the city in which I live. With the following code I get the source code of a page that shows, by pages, the first 100 results of a total of 247 schools:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.madrid.org/wpad_pub/run/j/BusquedaAvanzada.icm"
post_call = {'Public title': 'S', 'cdMuni': '079', 'cdNivelEdu': '6545'}
r = requests.post(url, data = post_call)
```

The page can be viewed [here](http://www.madrid.org/wpad_pub/run/j/BusquedaAvanzada.icm?titularidadPublica=S&cdMuni=079&cdNivelEdu=6545).

On that page there is a button that activates a javascript function to download a csv file with all 247 results. I was thinking of using Selenium to download this file, but I have seen, using Tamper Data, that when the button is pressed a POST call occurs, in which the parameter `codCentrosExp` is sent with the codes of the 247 colleges. The parameter looks like this:

```
CodCentrosExp = 28077877%3B28077865%3B28063751%3B28018392%3B28018393%...(thus up to the 247 codes)
```

This makes my work easier, since I do not have to download the csv file, open it, select the code column, etc. And I could do it with Tamper Data, but my question is: how can I get that parameter with my Python script, without having to use Tamper Data?

---

I finally found the parameter in the page's source code, and extracted them as follows:

```
schools = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
school_codes = schools.findAll(Attrs = {"name": "codCentrosExp", "value": re.compile("^.+$")})[0]["value"]
school_codes = school_codes.split(";")
```

Anyway, if anyone knows how to respond to the original question, I would be grateful to know how it could be done.

Comment: Link is not working

Comment: I'm sorry. It's fixed.

Comment: You can list down the answer if it is relevant or delete the question

Comment: I don't know the answer. I mean, the link is fixed.